# Python imports by folder module

Tags: python, import

I have a directory structure:

```
example.py
templates/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

`a.py` and `b.py` have only one class, named the same as the file (because they are cheetah templates). For purely style reasons, I want to be able to import and use these classes in `example.py` like so:

```
import templates

t = templates.a()
```

Right now I do that by having this in the template folder's `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ["a", "b"]
from . import *
```

However, this seems pretty poor (and maybe superfluous), and doesn't even do what I want, as I have to use the classes like this:

```
t = templates.a.a()
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid repeating `from <whatever> import *` 25 times, you need a loop, such as:

```
import sys

def _allimports(modnames)
  thismod = sys.modules[__name__]

  for modname in modnames:
    submodname = '%s.%s' % (thismod, modname)
    __import__(submodname)
    submod = sys.modules[submodname]
    thismod.__dict__.update(submod.__dict__)

_allimports('a b c d e'.split())  # or whatever
```

I'm putting the meaningful code in a function because (a) it's always best [[for performance and to avoid polluting the module's namespace]], (b) in this particular case it also avoids accidents (e.g., some submodule might define a name `thismod` or `modnames`... so it's important to keep those names that we're using in the loop local to the function, **not** module globals, so they can't be accidentally trampled;-).

If you want to enforce the fact that a module named `modname` only has one class (or other global) with the same name, change the last statement of the loop to:

```
    setattr(thismod, modname, getattr(submod, modname))
```

Comment: thanks! any thoughts on whether what I'm trying to do/what I have now is a good idea at all?

Comment: @colinmarc, I approve of your being skeptical about using such (deep) introspection / (slight) metaprogramming in production code, but you don't really have much of an alternative here -- the `a.py` &c files with class `a` are (I believe) a Cheetah given, and asking users to always do `from templates import a` (&c) then use `a.a()` (&c) does feel somewhat redundant (I might go for it, but only because I'm an evangelist for "always import a **module** -- **never** a package, **never** anything from _inside_ a module" and a sworn enemy of `import *`...;-) -- most people are more reasonable!-)

Comment: @colinmarc, sure, if you can have all the classes in a `template.py` in lieu of the current `template` directory/package, that will be much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

In your `__init__.py`:

```
from a import *
from b import *
```

Now all of `a`'s contents will be in `templates`, as will all of `b`'s contents.

Comment: is there a way to do this without a line for each? I actually have like 25 templates

Comment: I'm a fan of simplicity.  I wouldn't mind adding one line to __init__.py every time I added another module.  Your taste may differ...

Answer (score 3):

I didn't even know you could have `from . import *`. My python interpreter complains about such statements. Still, to your problem, you could do:

```
# __init__.py
from . import a, b
a = a.a
b = a.b
```

you can now use

```
# example.py
import templates
t = templates.a()
```

other solution:

```
# __init__.py
from a import *
from b import *
```

Comment: the "from . import..." is a relative import, which usually isn't a very good idea.