# Dynamic module import of class list from module given its full path

Tags: python, dynamic-import

First, it seems proper to me to state that I've read over the following questions:

- [Python imports by folder module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027091/python-imports-by-folder-module)
- [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

And, I don't feel like they address my use case.  That said, here's my question:

**How can I dynamically import from a configuration file like this:**

```
[imports]
/var/imports/foo.py = baz monkey
/var/imports/bar.py = ape
```

So that I can call the known objects via RESTful interface like this.

```
# http://localhost/data?operation=get&class=baz&id=1
def handler(object):
  def handle(self):
    cls = instantiate(request.args["class"])
    meth = request.args["operation"]
    return getattr(cls,meth,request.args)
```

And it could respond with the result of get() on an instance of that class.

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understood the question. Where the import configuration fits in this code? How and why do you use it?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing addressed by webapp frameworks like Django. Additionally, you seem to make no distinction between classes and instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch of a class registry you could use like this:

```
class ClassRegistry(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.classes = {}

    def add_file_classes(self, fname, class_list):
        globals = {}
        exec open(fname) in globals
        for class_name in class_list:
            self.classes[class_name] = getattr(globals, class_name)

    def get_class(self, class_name):
        return self.classes[class_name]
```

Read your config file and invoke `add_file_classes` like this:

```
reg = ClassRegistry()
reg.add_file_classes("/var/imports/foo.py", ["baz", "monkey"])
reg.add_file_classes("/var/imports/bar.py", ["ape"])
```

then later:

```
cls = reg.get_class("baz")
```

Note that we aren't actually importing the files, simply executing them and collecting their results.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the 2nd link again. It already mentions `imp.load_source`:

```
import imp

# some sort of shared dict for everything imported
loaded = {}

def load(path, from_list):
    # load the path
    module = imp.load_source( "dummy", path)
    for name in from_list:
        # add the names
        loaded[name] = getattr(module, name)

#lets say you have this:
data = "/var/imports/foo.py", ["baz"]
load(*data)
print loaded['baz'] # whatever foo.baz was
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
def instantiate( clsname ):
    obj = loaded[clsname]
    return obj()
```

I hope this gets you started.